# OpenGL incorrect texture coords only with multiple textured quads

Tags: c, opengl, textures

When I have multiple textured quads that use the same texture but at different coords the textures get morphed. Here's what my code looks like:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);    glTexCoords2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(32, 0);    glTexCoords2f(.5, 0);
    glVertex2f(32, 32);    glTexCoords2f(.5, .5);
    glVertex2f(0, 32);    glTexCoords2f(0, .5);
glEnd();

glTranslatef(32, 0, 0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);    glTexCoords2f(.5, .5);
    glVertex2f(32, 0);    glTexCoords2f(1, .5);
    glVertex2f(32, 32);    glTexCoords2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, 32);    glTexCoords2f(.5, 1);
glEnd();
```

Does anybody know what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: "the textures get morphed" What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling glTexCoord and glVertex in the wrong order. glVertex should always be the last attribute called to complete a vertex.

Should be:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoords2f(0, 0);    glVertex2f(0, 0);    
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. It's always the simplest mistakes that are hardest to find.